# UICollectionView don't show all content when scrolling horizontally

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview

[image: content in CollectionView]In my case,I only have one Section,and the section has 11 items.The problem is I can not scroll it to the last items.I can only scroll a very small distance from left to the right direction and it give me a bounce back.
Here is my code:

```
class RecommendGameView: UIView {

   //...
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let layout = gameCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 90)
        gameCollectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
                gameCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionGameCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: kGameCellID)
        gameCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: kEdgeInsetMargin, bottom: 0, right: kEdgeInsetMargin)
    }
}
    extension RecommendGameView : UICollectionViewDataSource {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return (groups?.count ?? 0)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = gameCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: kGameCellID, for: indexPath) as! CollectionGameCell
            cell.group = groups![indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your collectionview frame ?

Comment: I have settled it on nib ,its width is 387 and height is 90.

Comment: Don't use fix size for layout. and test with removing contentInset of your collection-view.